Inverse :belongs_to for successful :has_many yields nil
I'm developing a plugin to Foreman (v3.5.1) to add support of CNAME records to the network interface model (Nic::Base): ForemanCnames (WIP). I'll first show you the associations that I want, where the red arrows indicate the defunct connection:

The Problem
While I can get (known) CNAMEs from a (known) NIC, I cannot get the NIC or domain for a given CNAME.
irb(main):001:0> n = Nic::Base.find(7958)
=> <Nic::Managed id: 7958, name: "satellite-test-01.scc.kit.edu", ...>

irb(main):002:0> a = n.host_aliases.first
=> <ForemanCnames::HostAlias id: 5, name: "newer-alias", nics_id: 7958, domains_id: 1>

irb(main):004:0> a.nic
=> nil

irb(main):006:0> a.domain
=> nil

irb(main):007:0> n.domain
=> <Domain id: 1, name: "scc.kit.edu", ...>

Rails Models
This is how HostAlias looks like
module ForemanCnames
  class HostAlias < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :domain
    belongs_to :nic, :class_name => '::Nic::Base', :inverse_of => :host_aliases

    validates :nics_id, :presence => true
    validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :domains_id}

    def to_s
      name
    end

    def cname
      Nic::Interface.find(nics_id).fqdn
    end
  end
end

The association for Nic::Base is done with a Concern
module ForemanCnames::Concerns::NicExtensions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :host_aliases, :foreign_key => :nics_id, :class_name => 'ForemanCnames::HostAlias', :inverse_of => :nic
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :host_aliases, allow_destroy: true
  end
end

The foreman_cnames_host_aliases table was created by database migration.
class CreateHostAliases < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :foreman_cnames_host_aliases do |t|
      # A primary key id column is added by default
      t.string :name, :limit => 255
      t.references :nics, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :domains, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

There is no association injected to Domain, since we don't need to find CNAMEs for a given domain.
Analysis
The functionality should be straight forward, as can be seen with HostAlias#cname.
irb(main):001:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.first.cname
=> "satellite-test-01.scc.kit.edu"

So HostAlias#nic should be trivial
def nic
  Nic::Base.find(nics_id)
end

I cannot tell what Rails tries, since there is no Ruby or SQL code to inspect.
irb(main):001:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.first.method(:nic).source_location
=> ["/usr/share/gems/gems/activerecord-6.1.7/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb", 102]

irb(main):002:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.first.nic.to_sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from lib/tasks/console.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_sql' for nil:NilClass)

irb(main):003:0> puts Nic::Base.find(7958).host_aliases.to_sql
SELECT "foreman_cnames_host_aliases".* FROM "foreman_cnames_host_aliases" WHERE "foreman_cnames_host_aliases"."nics_id" = 7958

:inverse_of
At first I had no :inverse_of option. But as I learned from various sources, it is mandatory when either :class_name and/or :accepts_nested_attributes_for are set:

nested_attrubutes not assosiate with parent object
Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord NestedAttributes
Exploring the :invers_of option on Rails model associations

That said though, whether :inverse_of is present or not does not alter the behavior. It probably would, if NICs were created with CNAMEs in one go (have not tested that).
Association Reflections
I can inspect the associations via the Rails console
irb(main):001:0> Nic::Base.reflect_on_association(:host_aliases)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x000055f4135d5090 @name=:host_aliases, @scope=nil, @options={:foreign_key=>:nics_id, :class_name=>"ForemanCnames::HostAlias", :inverse_of=>:nic, :autosave=>true}, @active_record=Nic::Base(id: integer, ...), @klass=ForemanCnames::HostAlias(id: integer, name: string, nics_id: integer, domains_id: integer), @plural_name="host_aliases", @constructable=true, @class_name="ForemanCnames::HostAlias", @inverse_name=:nic, @foreign_key="nics_id", @active_record_primary_key="id", @inverse_of=#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x000055f411e906f0 @name=:nic, ...>>

irb(main):002:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:nic)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x000055f411e906f0 @name=:nic, @scope=nil, @options={:class_name=>"Nic::Base", :inverse_of=>:host_aliases}, @active_record=ForemanCnames::HostAlias(id: integer, name: string, nics_id: integer, domains_id: integer), @klass=Nic::Base(id: integer, ...), @plural_name="nics", @constructable=true, @foreign_key="nic_id", @class_name="Nic::Base", @inverse_name=:host_aliases, @inverse_of=#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x000055f4135d5090 @name=:host_aliases ...>>

irb(main):003:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:domain)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x000055f411e48170 @name=:domain, @scope=nil, @options={}, @active_record=ForemanCnames::HostAlias(id: integer, name: string, nics_id: integer, domains_id: integer), @klass=nil, @plural_name="domains", @constructable=true>

Looking at those, it seems wrong to me, that the foreign keys for :nic and :domain are not pluralized.
irb(main):001:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:nic).association_primary_key
=> "id"

irb(main):002:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:nic).foreign_key
=> "nic_id"

irb(main):003:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:domain).association_primary_key
=> "id"

irb(main):004:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:domain).foreign_key
=> "domain_id"

irb(main):005:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias
=> ForemanCnames::HostAlias(id: integer, name: string, nics_id: integer, domains_id: integer)

irb(main):006:0> ForemanCnames::HostAlias.reflect_on_association(:nic).table_name
=> "nics"

Presumably, that came from the private method ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection#derive_foreign_key? It takes the name of the association and appends "_id" to it, hence, "nic_id" and "domain_id". Though I cannot tell whether that is important.
Sidenotes
At some point I probably want to find CNAMEs for a host. But that should be something similar to has_many :host_aliases, :through => :interfaces on Host::Base. In other words, :through is not the solution to my current problem.

You're right that pluralization matters but you're drawing the wrong conclusions. These are the naming conventions for foreign key columns:


Foreign keys - These fields should be named following the pattern singularized_table_name_id (e.g., item_id, order_id). These are the fields that Active Record will look for when you create associations between your models.


So Foreman is actually using the correct name for it's column. The foreign key column is a reference to one single row on the other table. It's the id of one item not all the items.
TableDefinition vs SchemaStatement

Apparently, references during table creation (in block form) works differently. I'll also adopt the alias belongs_to, which then is literally identical to the model's association.

This is just wrong.
references is a method of TableDefinition which is just a table based abstraction that lets you
modify multiple columns on the table instead of the single column operation methods in SchemaStatement.
add_reference(:foos, :bar)

Becomes:
change_table :foos do |t|
  t.references :bar
end  

Which is way less clunky when you add more columns to the migration.
They do not produce different results as far as the schema is concerned. This is how they are implemented.
def references(*args, **options)
  args.each do |ref_name|
    ReferenceDefinition.new(ref_name, **options).add_to(self)
  end
end

def add_reference(table_name, ref_name, **options)
  ReferenceDefinition.new(ref_name, **options).add(table_name, self)
end

The actual difference really is that add_to adds the changes to the table definintion and add immediately fires the SQL query to alter the table.
Inverses

At first I had no :inverse_of option. But as I learned from various sources, it is mandatory

Those sources or your interpretation are wrong. Your assocations will work just fine even without an inverse.
What inverses actually do is create an in-memory link between the records so that you don't incur the performance penality of an unessicary database query when you do foo.bars.first.foo. So inverses are good but your app won't blow up without them.
Automatic inverses are derived from the name of the assocation so it's wise to specify it if it cannot be derived from the name of the assocation. This isn't actually explicitly linked to the class_name option.
All together then the right way
# Acronyms should be ALLCAPS
# setup an inflection!
module ForemanCNAMES
  class HostAlias < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Validations are added by default since Rails 5
    belongs_to :domain
    belongs_to :nic, 
      class_name: '::Nic::Base', 
      inverse_of: :host_aliases
    has_one :interface, through: :nic

    def to_s
      name
    end

    def cname
      interface.fqdn
    end
  end
end

# Do not use :: when defining classes/modules
# If you do it right and reopen the module all constants will be resolved
# from your namespace
module ForemanCNAMES
  # Don't use module names and excessive nesting that provides no value
  # like Concerns, Modules, Classes
  module NicExtensions
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      has_many :host_aliases 
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :host_aliases, 
        allow_destroy: true
    end
  end
end


Thank you very much for clarifying my mistakes! Regarding :invers_of, I understand that it isn't universally mandatory and at my current development stage of the plugin it is optional (I mentioned that the error was the same with or without :inverse_of). It will matter as soon as I attempt to create new NICs with CNAMEs from the start. Because, in that scenario, Rails will attempt to create the record in the host aliases table before the referenced record in the nics table, right? It can't reference anything that doesn't exist yet.

Thank you also for your comments on coding style and naming conventions. The names are chosen this way to mimic what Foreman has done. I agree that it is unnecessary fluff, but it should help me and others figure out which module from ForemanCNAMES impacts what module in Foreman. Once the plugin has progressed further in development, I can still refactor the module names.

Two questions remain regarding the validation of the HostAlias database schema: Does Rails automatically ensure that CNAMEs with the same name are unique per domain? I fear that without it, CNAMEs are not ensured to be unique. The primary key of the host aliases table is id, not name after all. An the second question is in another comment, due to character limitation. :-)

Second question on validation: I'm surprised that you added has_one interfaces, through: nic. Can you confirm that I inferred your intention correctly? As can be seen with your cname method, interface yields the same as nic. With the slight difference, that Rails will select the FQDN from a joined query (SELECT fqdn FROM foreman_cnames_host_aliases AS c JOIN nics AS n ON c.nic_id = n.id WHERE c.id=?), rather than first getting the CNAME database record and using its nic_id to fetch the NIC record in a second database query?

It's has_one :interface, through: :nic. Adding an indirect assocation lets you eager load it and is a lot less smelly as it limits the knowledge that HostAlias has about Nic::Interface. It just knows that it can get that assocation through the other one but doesn't need to know what foreign to use to fetch it.

Rails won't actually eager load it though unless you explitly do it. But just by using the association intead Rails will just load it once instead of every time the HostAlias#cname method is called.

I must still be doing "something wrong", because, after adopting your proposal for the NicExtensions, I find that :class_name as well as :foreign_key are mandatory. Without :class_name Rails fails to find the constant Nic::Base::HostAlias and without :foreign_key the database query fails, because the host aliases table has no column base_id.

Also, has_one :interface, through: :nic seems to not do what you expected, since it raises an error for me in the Rails console: "ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "interface" or :interface in model Nic::Base." It is true that Nic::Base has no interface association - because, why would it associate to itself?

Pluralization is the Issue!
In accordance with the Ruby on Rails Guide, references use the pluralized names on database migrations, which creates the columns nics_id and domains_id. The association :belongs_to uses the singular variant and :has_many the plural.
But, Foreman has the :belongs_to association between NICs and the domains...
irb(main):006:0> Nic::Base.reflect_on_association(:domain).foreign_key
=> "domain_id"

... and the database table reference in singular.
Where did I go wrong?
@Max explains my actual mistakes in his reply.
Apparently, references during table creation (in block form) works differently. I'll also adopt the alias belongs_to, which then is literally identical to the model's association.
After updating all "nics_id" and "domains_id" occurences...
irb(main):001:0> n = Nic::Base.find(7958)
=> #<Nic::Managed id: 7958, ...>

irb(main):002:0> a = n.host_aliases.first
=> #<ForemanCnames::HostAlias id: 1, name: "new-alias", nic_id: 7958, domain_id: 1>

irb(main):003:0> a.nic
=> #<Nic::Managed id: 7958, ...>

irb(main):004:0> a.domain
=> #<Domain id: 1, name: "scc.kit.edu", ...>

irb(main):005:0> a.nic.fqdn
=> "satellite-test-01.scc.kit.edu"

irb(main):006:0> a.domain.name
=> "scc.kit.edu"

